# Azure Function - Publishing Failed - RequestTimeout

Tags: deployment, timeout, azure-functions

I have a basic Azure Function app. When I try to publish the app, I receive an error that says "error : The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://... failed with HTTP status code RequestTimeout.".

This app is a .NET Standard app. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio#publish-the-project-to-azure). The difference is, my app has an Event Hub Trigger instead of the Http Trigger shown in the documentation. I don't understand why i'm getting a Timeout during deployment. I also don't know how to get past this.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Here are the logs.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject.Functions, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>MyProject.Functions -> C:\MyProject\MyProject.Functions\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\MyProject.Functions.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
  Publish Started
  MyProject.Functions -> C:\MyProject\MyProject.Functions\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\MyProject.Functions.dll
  MyProject.Functions -> C:\MyProject\MyProject.Functions\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\
  Publishing C:\MyProject\MyProject.Functions\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\MyProject.Functions - 20181101105531356.zip to https://my-project.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy...
C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.23\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.ZipDeploy.targets(42,5): error : The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://my-project.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code RequestTimeout. [C:\MyProject\MyProject.Functions\MyProject.Functions.csproj]
```

Comment: Do you have any logs which you can share.

Comment: @Baskar - I just added the logs.

Comment: Did you try by stopping your Function App if you are trying to publish to an existing function ?

Comment: @Baskar - I did try stopping the Function app. Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Some previous issues which might help - It looks like eventhough it fails the resource would have been updated based on this thread. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2589

Comment: looks like a backend issue. I'll need your app name to look its logs. You can share it directly or indirectly using one of these methods https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately or https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Answer (score 3):

According to this:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file

you should be able to pass `?isAsync=true` to the zipdeploy url (so it would be: 'https://my-project.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true'

This requests resolves faster without a timeout and then you can grab the location header from the response, which you can poll to see the status of your deployment.

Comment: Worked for me, even though it appeared to generate a completely mangled URL (https://{functionname}.scm.azurewebsites.net?isAsync=true/api/zipdeploy)

Comment: Same issue here, unfortunately isAsync has no effect

Answer (score 3):

In my case this error was because of the version of packages in my .csproj file. After updating them there was not error and the publish was successful.

Comment: Creating a new profile worked for me too,

Comment: I tried "everything". Only after updating nuget packages did it start working again!

Comment: Yep. Updating the NuGet packages helped! Probably one of the Functions packages.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this recently and spent 2 complete days trying to fix it. Tried most of the solutions suggested here and on other posts.

What finally worked for me is removing my Publish settings and creating a new one by uploading a brand new .PublishSettings file.

**How to get .PublishSettings file?**

On Azure Portal, on your Function App, click on "Get Publish Profile"
[image: Azure Portal]

And will automatically start downloading it.

**How to Upload Publish Profile?**

When trying to Publish the project from Visual Studio, click on New -> Select "Import Profile"
[image: Import Profile]

And Browse your .PublishSettings file.

Then, just select this new profile (if it's not selected already), and click on Publish button as you would usually do.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an issue with two things:

1] Visual Studio and Azure are flaky. Timeouts in a working scenario are still somewhat regular, on a bad day happening about 50-75% of the time for me. This is with an 80mb function app, not super big and I have gigabit Internet.

2] Someone deleted the file share for the storage. I had to fix `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` to point to the right storage connection string, and I had to update `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` to point to a valid file share name, which I had to create in the storage resource group matching `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` connection string.

If you are using a development and production function slot, I would suggest to make `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` deployment slot settings, that way you can link to a production and development storage environment. This is especially handy if you are using tables or blob storage and don't want to have to prefix or suffix all your table names or keys. In my opinion these two settings should be slots by default.

Once I did these changes I could publish, still dealing with the intermittent timeouts.

The error messaging with Azure function publishing is bad to non-existant, with any kind of configuration or resource errors simply causing a timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when using Visual Studio. Very frustrating.
But then I just used the zip file that VS created and used

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n \
<app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

to publish.

You can find more options in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently.

I'm not sure if they are related, but it started working fine after updating the NuGet package "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" to v3.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the profile to use WebDeploy was the only way i could update my Azure Function.

When downloading the Profiles from the Azure Portal, and importing to VS - i noticed it imported 2 profiles. 1 for Zip, and another for Web Deploy method for uploading.

Trying the Zip publish profile, failed, but the WebDeploy 2nd Profile - did work and update perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new profile with the same configurations.