# Publish Failed Error while publishing Azure functions on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am getting error while publishing azure functions on azure portal.I tried lot of things and visited lot of links but didn't find any suitable soltuion.

Below is the output in output window.

```
     Azure Application Settings updated.
1>------ Build started: Project: AwepayReconcile.DAL, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Models\AwepayContext.cs(26,10,26,214): warning CS1030: #warning: 'To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.'
1>AwepayReconcile.DAL -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.DAL\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\AwepayReconcile.DAL.dll
1>Done building project "AwepayReconcile.DAL.csproj".
2>------ Build started: Project: AwepayReconcile.DL, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Infrastructure\Extensions.cs(34,42,34,44): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(177,36,177,38): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(210,36,210,38): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(304,30,304,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(403,30,403,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(40,36,40,42): warning CS0169: The field 'ReconcileService.hssfwb' is never used
2>Services\ReconcileService.cs(38,33,38,38): warning CS0169: The field 'ReconcileService.sheet' is never used
2>Services\AzureBlobStorageService.cs(29,29,29,41): warning CS0414: The field 'AzureBlobStorageService._appSettings' is assigned but its value is never used
2>AwepayReconcile.DL -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.DL\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\AwepayReconcile.DL.dll
2>Done building project "AwepayReconcile.DL.csproj".
3>------ Build started: Project: AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp.dll
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
  Publish Started
  AwepayReconcile.DAL -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.DAL\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\AwepayReconcile.DAL.dll
  AwepayReconcile.DL -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.DL\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\AwepayReconcile.DL.dll
  AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp.dll
  AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp -> D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out\
  Publishing D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp - 20190320182641787.zip to https://awepayreconcileazurefunctionsapp20190320061400.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy...
C:\Users\tejinder.s\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.26\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.ZipDeploy.targets(42,5): error : The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://awepayreconcileazurefunctionsapp20190320061400.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code RequestTimeout. [D:\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp\AwepayReconcile.AzureFunctionsApp.csproj]
```

Please help me to git rid of this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you tried changing your version of `Newtonsoft.Json` to 11.0.2 as the error suggests?

Comment: @GregH, Yes, I have changed the version of `Newtonsoft.json`. but it didn't work.I have updated the output above after changing the `Newtonsoft.json` version.Please check.

Comment: well some things to check would be that your azure service is running, firewall settings on your computer, close fiddler (or any applications which set up a reverse proxy) on your computer before publishing

Comment: also, take a peek at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103896/azure-function-publishing-failed-requesttimeout

Answer (score 1):

> When deploying your function app to Windows, you should set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `1` and publish with zip deployment.

[Zip deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) is a feature of Azure App Service that lets you deploy your function app project to the `wwwroot` directory. The project is packaged as a .zip deployment file. The same APIs can be used to deploy your package to the `d:\home\data\SitePackages` folder.

With the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` app setting value of `1`, the zip deployment APIs copy your package to the `d:\home\data\SitePackages` folder instead of extracting the files to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. It also creates the `packagename.txt` file. The function app is then run from the package after a restart, and `wwwroot` becomes read-only.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package).

Comment: could you please make it more clear? As I try to publish the code from visual studio. Do I need to create a Zip of my project? I am little bit confused.

Comment: No, you just need go to the azure function on portal and add `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `1` in `application settings`.

Comment: I have checked that in application settings , `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is already set to `1` .